# Not able to read and write between Java Socket/Client

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am trying to establish a connection between a server and a client in Java, using java.net. I manage to connect, but not to send any data. I have pasted the code and the outputs:

Server Code:

```
ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(999);
Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
System.out.println("Connected to: " + connectionSocket.toString());
DataOutputStream outToClient = newDataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
outToClient.writeBytes("Testing connection");
```

Client Code:

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("130.236.248.52", 999);
BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
System.out.println("[From server:] " + modifiedSentence);
```

Server output:
Connected to: Socket[addr=/130.236.248.54,port=51535,localport=999]

Client output:

Comment: did you try to close the connectionSocket after writing to the client?

Comment: Yes, I have 
    clientSocket.close();
after the println in the Client Code

Comment: I mean on the server `connectionSocket.close()` after `outToClient.writeBytes("Testing connection");`

Comment: Yes, I also have welcomeSocket.close(); after the write statement.

Comment: No, you'd need to close the `connectionSocket` to cut communication with the client.  Closing `welcomeSocket` just stops the server from listening for any new connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a [`BufferedWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) to write text (just like you're using a BufferedReader to read text)
2. Call `flush()` on your writer to force the output to go through
3. If you're calling `readLine()` on the client side, there needs to be an end-of-line to read.

```
    BufferedWriter outToClient = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream()));
    outToClient.write("Testing connection");
    outToClient.newLine();
    outToClient.flush();
```

Comment: The new line might not be needed for the last line sent by the server before the connection is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading lines but you aren't writing lines. You need to either append a line terminator or use one of the classes that exports a println() method, and call it.